# Помогите остановить таймер

Tags: таймер

Скрипт начинает кликать по таймеру при нажатии клавиши F10 и должен перестать кликать при нажатии F9, при повторном нажатии F10 продолжить кликать.

```js
var timer;

document.onkeydown = function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 121:
         timer = setInterval(() => {
             document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].click();
         }, 5000);
        break;
        case 120:
       timer = clearInterval(timer);        
 }
};
```

Беда в том что клик по таймеру не останавливается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что делает F10 (в Windows)? Подумайте.

```js
var timer;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 121:
      if (!timer) {
        timer = setInterval(() => console.log("timer"), 1000);
        console.log("timer started");
      } else {
        console.log("timer already running");
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      break;
    case 120:
      if (timer) {
        timer = clearInterval(timer);
        console.log("timer stopped");
      } else {
        console.log("timer not running");
      }
      break;
  }
};
```

Comment: Можно задать вопрос? Тоже касательно _setInterval_.

Comment: @UModeL Конечно можно.

Comment: ок. Допустим, я создаю `<div>` и создаю своё свойство (пусть будет `div.timer`). В процессе делаю так `div.timer = setInterval()`. Два вопроса даже: 1) остаётся ли этот таймер глобальным и 2) что происходит с таким запущенным таймером, если удалить `<div>` ?

Comment: @UModeL Ответы: 1. Да. 2. Ничего не происходит, таймер продолжает работать. Значение, которое возвращает `setInterval`, это не объект со сроком жизни до сборки мусора, а идентификатор таймера - если вывести в консоль, увидим целое число.

Comment: таким образом, если просто удалять, не останавливая, то рано или поздно "бадабум" наступит таки, так? А возможно ли получить список идентификаторов запущенных таймеров на странице?

Comment: @UModeL Смотря что мы считаем "бадабум"-ом. О такой встроенной возможности мне неизвестно. Но можно переопределить функции `setInterval` и `clearInterval`.

Comment: ))) я имел в виду утечки и/или падение, тормоза из-за количества запущенных процессов.

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не про поведенческие стратегии windows и F10 спрашивал, но все равно благодарю, это помогло решить проблему, сделал так:

```js
var timer;
var li = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1];

document.onkeydown = function(e){
    switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 121:
         if (!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        li.click();
    }, 5000);
}
e.preventDefault();
break;
        case 120:
            timer = clearInterval(timer);
    e.preventDefault();
    break;
     }
};
```

Comment: Зачем Вы опять скопировали код из моего ответа?

Comment: У меня было несколько вариаций кода, сюда сбросил одно из, а из вашего кода забрал только e.preventDefault();

Comment: При чем здесь "поведенческие стратегии"? Вы поняли, почему не работает без `e.preventDefault();`?